# Creating demo data for rails application on per account basis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-experience

I would like to create some sample data for a user when they register so that they do not have to start with a blank canvas.

I am presently defining lots of static data in classes which I then iterate over, however setting up relationships is cumbersome and I think that this is quite brittle.

I think that having some demo fixtures (separate from my test set) would be a good way to do this, but as records are tied to an account I can't see how I can insert this data and attach it to the account when loading the fixtures.

This might not even be the best approach, but if there is a better way then please let me know.

Comment: maybe do something with Faker  / Factory girl ?

Comment: Faker might work for some of the content, but a large part will be domain specific.

Answer (score 0):

Every RAILS application has `seeds.rb` present in `db/` folder.So as the name says,it is used to seed your db by default records that you may want.
So this is how i am using my seeds.rb.Creating many records,constants and then to put those records in your db,just run `rake db:seed` assuming you have db ready.See [HERE](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data) for more infor

**my seeds.rb**

```
###seed eventype table with default values
["birthday","farewell","party"].each do |f|
    EventType.find_or_create_by({name:f.upcase})
end

###create users with random names
##after creating users,create associated fields

%w[mike john paul allen harry betty].each_with_index do |name,index|
  @user = User.find_or_create_by({email:"user_#{name}@gmail.com"})

  ##user has_one address
  @user.create_address({:address_2=>"street 1,near berry lane"})

  ##user has_many pictures
  @user.pictures.create!({:title=>"Title of the picture",:picture => File.new("#{Rails.root}/public/images/test.jpg")}) 


end
```

You can even use  `(0..6).each do` loop to create n records as you wish in db.
for example:-

```
 (0..100).each do 
   ###create user/pictures etc
 end
```

***However you must be careful to follow all validations and create valid record else this wont work.
for example,if in user model,you are expecting username as well,then in seeds.rb,you must pass the username so that it passes the validation easily.***

=========================================================================
**IF you dont want to use db seed**,you can use a callbacks `on: :create`(i dont prefer observers).Simple example can be :

```
##in user.rb
after_commit :create_default_account, on: :create

def create_default_account
 ##assuming user has_one :account
 self.build_account({:name=>"Default account"})
end
```

**HOPE IT HELPS**

Comment: I don't need to seed the database, rather create content inside a user's account when a user registers such that they have their own demo content to play with.

Comment: i have updated my answer with other option apart from seed.try that out.@apchester